# typescript import with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browserify

I'm just starting with front-end web developpement(javascript hell with all these package manager/bundler) and I'm trying to use typescript + browsify

so I create a index.ts file and download the `uniq` module(using npm) just to test **ts** file compilation

here is my **index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/uniq/uniq.d.ts" />
import {unique} from "uniq";

var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

console.log(unique(data));
```

**uniq.d.ts**

```
// Type definitions for uniq
// Project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniq
// Definitions by: Hans Windhoff <https://github.com/hansrwindhoff>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped


interface Uniq{
  <T>(ip:Array<T>): Array<T>;
}

declare var uniq :Uniq;

declare module "uniq" {
export = uniq;
}
```

**directory structure**

```
.
├── entry.ts
├── node_modules
│   └── uniq
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── test
│       │   └── test.js
│       ├── uniq.d.ts
│       └── uniq.ts
└── package.json
```

but when I try to compile the **index.ts** I got this error :

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'uniq'.
```

Comment: Did you install the `typings` definition for it?  You currently have your reference pointing to the definition file in the typings folder, but I don't see that in your directory structure.

Comment: @DaveV repair the mistake, i was just verifying that the d.ts file need not to be in the same folder as the .js file, still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First

you probably have the path wrong:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/uniq/uniq.d.ts" />
```

Maybe `../../node_modules/uniq/uniq.d.ts`. Instead of britle paths like this please use `tsconfig.json` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/tsconfig.html

## Second

Based on the `.d.ts` you showed your import `import {unique} from "uniq";` is also wrong. It should be `import unique = require('uniq')` since its a single function export. You will get an error about this anyways after you fix first. Enjoy